# Using cross-validation for lasso regression to find optimal tuning parameter λ

Tags: r, lasso-regression

By using cross-validation, I want to find the optimal tuning parameter lambda and the corresponsing coefficients for a LASSO regression that predicts the variable "income".

I am pretty new to all of this and very confused about the order of the steps (and everything else).

My code so far:

```
library(glmnet)
set.seed(1)
grid <- 10^seq(10, -2, length.out=100)

x <- model.matrix(income~., data)
y <- data$income

train <- sample(1:nrow(x), nrow(x)/2)
test <- (-train)


# build the model
lasso.model <- cv.glmnet(x[train, ], y[train], alpha=1, lambda=grid) #sets unimportant variables to zero
plot(lasso.model)

best_lambda <- lasso.model$lambda.min # best lambda equals 0.01


#refit our model using the full data set and best_lambda
lasso.model.full <-glmnet(x, y, alpha=1)
  
lasso.predict <- predict(lasso.model.full, type="coefficients",
                         s=best_lambda)
lasso.predict[-c(1,2), ] # coefficients for optimal lambda
                        -lasso.predict)^2)
```

Right now, I get as the optimal lambda 0.01, which makes me suspicious that I have done something wrong.

What do I have to do differently?